# Why do you have to free memory allocated by malloc but not the memory that you allocate to say a function you declared like int or bool?

Tags: c, malloc

As the title says, what is the reason you free memory that you allocated using malloc, but never free memory allocated to a variable like an integer?

Comment: Because the memory used for local variables is automatically released when the function returns.

Comment: @user3386109 So when malloc allocates memory it is similar to a global variable in some sense?

Comment: In the sense that the variables keeps existing, also after returning from the function, yes.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie hmm, but by the end of the program all memory is de allocated right?

Comment: All memory is freed when the program ends, which will happen soon if you keep allocating memory and not freeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler allocate space for local variables on the stack just by moving the stack pointer with the space needed for the variables. Before return, the stack is restore.

When you call `malloc`, the memory space is allocated in a so called the *heap*. The *heap* is managed to keep allocated blocks until `free` or `realloc` is called.